# Why is my array.length returning such a high number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string

For some reason I can push JSON objects to my array "list", but when I call its .length, it seems that I'm getting the number of characters rather than number of items.

**UPDATE: See answers for solution. My script wasn't returning *characters*, it was looping through exponentially.**

```
$.getJSON('[omitted].php?callback=?',function(d,item){
    var list = []
    alert('Length: '+d.length) // d consists of 271 JSON objects, d.length = 271
    for (i=0;i<d.length;i++){
        $.each(d,function(){ // for each JSON object we add...
            list.push({'name':this.name,'href':this.href,'img':this.img})
        })
        if (i==d.length){
        alert('Completed - Length: '+list.length) // list.length = 44711. Why?
        }
    }
})
```

Note that when I use alert(list) I see:

```
[object,Object][object,Object][object,Object] ...
```

Rather than an array:

```
[[object,Object][object,Object][object,Object] ... ]
```

Comment: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), please? (As for it not showing up as an array, the implicit join character is `,`. The brackets are not added.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this...

```
$.each(d,function(){
```

should be this...

```
$.each(d[i],function(){
```

Otherwise you're looping over the same `d` structure once for every item in `d`.

Comment: Thanks, all answers were very useful. I'll upvote as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Loop though d
for (i=0;i<d.length;i++){
    //loop through d 
    $.each(d,function(){ // for each JSON object we add...
        list.push({'name':this.name,'href':this.href,'img':this.img})
    })
    if (i==d.length){
    alert('Completed - Length: '+list.length) // list.length = 44711. Why?
    }
}
```

Do you see the problem?

You are basically doing this:

```
var list = [];
for (var i=0;i<d.length;i++){
    for (var j=0;j<d.length;j++){
        list.push( {} );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, all answers were very useful. I'll upvote as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

Lets see, the basic structure of a each statement

```
$.each(mixedVar, function(index, item) {
     //Here index, is not an array but singular item's index, so whenever
     // index.length will be applied it will be taken as a variables, that a list/collection/array
});
```

In the same way, your `d` is also returning a item's index, which is a mixed variable, neither a list nor an array.

Comment: Thanks, all answers were very useful. I'll upvote as soon as I can.